# Alternativas para desenvolvimento de VBA no Office

Tags: c#, .net, vba, microsoft-office

No trabalho tenho uma grande base de códigos escrita em VBA (aproximadamente 13 projetos ativos), tanto para aplicações Access ou Excel.

Venho tentando refatorar algumas coisas, porem diversos fatores estão me dificultando meu trabalho, como:

- A IDE que acompanha o VBA é muito antiga (baseada no [Visual Studio 6, de 1998](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_6.0))
- O VBA em si tem muitas limitações se comparado a linguagens como C# e Java
- Os projetos em VBA ficam agregados ao arquivo `.xls` ou `.mdb`, o que torna difícil seu uso dentro de softwares de controle de versão (Git)
- Temos mais de um desenvolvedor, o que torna trabalhar em projetos simultaneamente inviável, pois não conseguimos versionar

Tento em vista esses pontos, estou pensando em alternativas para contornar esses problemas causando o mínimo de impacto.

Não é viável migrar de uma só vez todos os projetos para uma nova arquitetura devido a complexidade de alguns.

Já tentei compilar DLLs em C# e interligá-las com o VBA a partir de `COM`, mas isso trouxe mais problemas do que ajudou.

#### Pergunta

Existe alguma forma de migrar gradualmente essas soluções em VBA, mesclando o que já existe hoje com uma nova arquitetura ?

Ou no pior dos casos, onde terei que permanecer com o VBA, como alterar a IDE padrão do VBA para alguma mais moderna que mantém a integração com o Office?

Comment: Para este fim eu tenho usado o `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`, migrando código gradativamente de `VBA` para `C#`. Você está a par deste namespace?

Comment: @Caffé para executar algumas rotinas do Access utilizo o `Interop`. Se não fosse ele já teria surtado para incluir novas funcionalidades.

Comment: Utilize o [RubberDuck](http://rubberduckvba.com/) para melhorar a IDE do VBA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solução oficial para fazer isto em .NET é o [Visual Studio Tools for Office](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Tools_for_Office). Não posso garantir que atende todas suas necessidades, mas ele parece resolver o que você postou.

Como o desenvolvimento é realizado no Visual Studio como uma aplicação qualquer fica claro que terá acesso às ferramentas e linguagens mais modernas, separação do documento e código e evitará os problemas de uso do COM direto (o VSTO acessa o COM internamente, mas é transparente).

Infelizmente desconheço a dificuldade de migração paulatina de uma tecnologia para outra até porque desconheço suas necessidades específicas. É possível que seja mais uma questão de planejamento, mas pode ser que tenha situações que dificultem isto. Aí provavelmente você não terá saída melhor.

VBA é para esquecer mesmo. Além desta solução posso citar uma alternativa que não conheço: [NetOffice](https://osdn.net/projects/netoffice/) - solução *open source* com facilidades para executar algumas tarefas com a API do Office para .NET.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: VSTO é uma alternativa interessante. Os únicos problemas que teria inicialmente é que ele requer o VS Professional no mínimo e até meados do ano que vem pelo menos estou preso no Office XP.

Answer (score 4):

Após um certo tempo utilizando essas tecnologias, acabei me deparando com a situação de ter que continuar desenvolvendo com o VBA.

Porém encontrei algumas alternativas que melhoraram meu fluxo de trabalho com esse tipo de ambiente:

**MZ-Tools**: um conjunto de ferramentas para a IDE do VBA que incluem melhorias como *Find and Replace*, *Code Templates*, documentação e outros recursos. Podemos encontrar a lista [desses recursos aqui](http://www.mztools.com/v3/features.aspx). Seu download é gratuito e [pode ser baixado aqui](http://www.mztools.com/v3/download.aspx).

**Orientação de Objetos**: sim, o VBA dá suporte a orientação a objetos, mas de forma bem limitada. Não existe [namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace) e a API da linguagem não é muito intuitiva, o que leva a uma série de idas e vindas na documentação da linguagem.

A solução nesse caso foi criar uma camada entre algumas funções nativas e o código, criando uma espécie de biblioteca separada em "pseudo-namespaces", similar as classes do [Zend Framework 1](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/reference.html). É preciso aplicar [alguns macetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14944666/are-there-any-pitfalls-in-using-class-modules-as-namespaces-in-vba) como pode ver nessa resposta do SO.

Leitura recomendada: [Organizing Code With Namespaces in VBA](http://bytecomb.com/organizing-code-with-namespaces-in-vba/)

**Versionamento**: os códigos VBA ficam agregados dentro do arquivo `.xls` em que ele é criado, porém existe a possibilidade de exportá-los para arquivos de texto.

Encontrei um *script* que exporta esses arquivos nesse [gist](https://gist.github.com/steve-jansen/7589478), porém ao pesquisar um pouco mais encontrei essa [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25985021/2099835), apontando para um projeto que exporta automaticamente esses arquivos ao salvar a planilha e importar novamente de forma bem simples. Esse projeto pode ser [encontrado aqui](https://github.com/hilkoc/vbaDeveloper).

A partir dos arquivos de código em texto, agora consigo utilizar o git normalmente e o código está versionado no repositório da empresa.

#### Conclusão

Mesmo estando preso a uma plataforma antiga e com muito código legado, é possível se trabalhar e ter produtividade com VBA. Como programadores temos que as vezes abrir mão das melhores ferramentas e trabalhar com o que é "oferecido", seja por questões políticas ou por restrições de escopo.

Recomendo que, caso seja possível, estude a migração para outras tecnologias e só em casos extremos mantenha projetos em VBA.